# Spring Cloud Gateway : client certificate hostname validation

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

Does someone know how to turn on client certificate hostname verification in Spring Cloud Gateway?

I know that Netty 4.* by default doesn't verify client certificate's hostname (https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/10362). I'm able to tweak configuration and enable the host verification.

However, created SSLEngine doesn't have peer hostname (value is always set to null), thus verification fails. Looks like reactor-netty's SSL Provider is always bootstrapped in a way to skip peer host.

Anyone lucky enough to have that working?

Answer (score 1):

Reactor Netty (and respectively Spring Cloud Gateway) enables this by default
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/8537#issuecomment-820928044

Comment: This is for HttpClient while I was looking for HttpServer. Sorry if that was not clear from original message. My problem is that SSLEngine is always getting created without peer host / port values thus failing hostname verification.